# Why did Microsoft Choose MVC to build ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I know what is ASP.net and I know what is MVC and some other Design patterns , my question is why did microsoft choose this design pattern ? why not ASP.net 3tiers or ASP.net AOP ...etc 
is it easier to program with , more powerful for building websites? in other words what are the advantages to use MVC instead of other Design Patterns with ASP.net?

Comment: Why not send an email and ask [Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/)? As far as the differences between ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC don't hesitate to use the search box located at the top right corner of this site. It will yield hundreds of discussions about this topic.

Comment: What would ASP.NET 3tiers be? ASP.NET is just the presentation tier. I've used it in 3-tier apps. I don't know AOP but skimming the Wikipedia article it seems to describe business logic again.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: read the question again please..

Comment: @M.H, it's after reading your question that I posted my comment :-) You are asking why did Microsoft choose MVC as pattern. What answer do you really expect? They choose it *because it's good* or do you really want to know the exact reason? In this case only *they* (Microsoft) can answer this question.

Comment: M.H - i too was quite a late 'devotee' of mvc (only 15 months ago) after doing webforms for 6 years. i just wonder why i waitied sooo long. i've never touched webforms since. it just melds with my mindset as to how things SHOULD be done, rather than my previous hoop-jumping based on page life cycles.. yuk!!

Comment: @jim: No more bending WebForms to do what we really want, hoorah!

Comment: spolto - thankfully, the over-inflated term (webforms) itself becomes redundant in favour of the more demure, modest and unambiguous - 'html view' .. :)

Comment: "ASP.net 3tiers or ASP.net AOP" - I think you're confusing patterns.  3 tier or AOP don't solve any of the presentation problems WebForms, MVP and MVC solve.

Comment: They chose MVC to build ASP.NET MVC, otherwise they would have had to change the name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MVC is a strong pattern and has proved very popular in other development communities including but not limited to Ruby on Rails. Wikipedia has a long list of [MVC web frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller). I guess Microsoft, didn't want to be left behind as more and more people migrated away from WebForms.

Answer (score 8):

My guess would be that it is a proven and very suitable pattern for the web. MVC fits very well with the stateless nature of the http protocol. And many other big web frameworks for other languages use the MVC pattern.

Comment: +1as well - your answer and spolto's combined would be the definitive answer